# To read the names of all files(or to get the link for it ) inside a google drive folder using python

Tags: python, excel, file, drive

How to read the names of all files or get the links for all files inside a google drive folder using python?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python   https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the google drive API. They have given an example where you get the list of files and folders in your home page.
[Example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python#step_2_configure_the_sample)
You can do more by checking out [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference).